# Python memory leak w complex workflow

Tags: python, memory

Python 3 question here.  I've been hunting down a memory leak for the past 3 days and cannot find it.  My code is way too complicated to post, but basically a REST API (flask) calls a forecasting routine, which in turn calls a submodule, which in turn asynchronously runs 1000s of calculations at once, returning them to a common object.  There are many complex data structures in the workflow, like dictionaries of dataframes.  No (major) global vars being used, but several functions do reference nonlocal ones.  Anyway, the memory blows up upon repeated running.

I've narrowed it down to the submodule, and the leak still happens even if asynchronous processing is turned off, and here is what is confusing.  If I run just the submodule, exit that scope, and look at the variables in Pycharm debugger, none of the big data structures are in scope anymore (which is desired).  But the memory is not getting freed.

I've tried the functionality in gc like collect() and get_objects.  I also tried some of the various libraries that return the count of references to types.  Nothing is obviously blowing up by reference count in terms of INCREASE per run, although I notice I generally have 43,000 references to "function", and 19,000 references to "dict", which makes me very worried that the dicts of dataframes are still around somehow.  I have tried explicit things to wipe the dicts, like setting them to None, dict.clear(), and del.  These run and the debugger says they are gone.

Few questions - I assume the GC is not freeing the memory because a reference, somehow, exists to some of these data structures.  But how could such a reference exist once I leave the scope of that function and provided nothing is defined globally?  Also, I would really like a simple way to just see all the objects in memory sorted by size.  Is that possible?

I know I've only provided general information, but my specific code is very complex and long, so I'm really looking for any general advice here from someone who has had such a problem before, or perhaps something I've written above rings a bell with someone...  any thoughts much appreciated.  thanks.

**EDIT:**

OK here is a simple loop which is conceptually not so different from what I am doing.  It just makes a dictionary of dataframes, over and over.  When I watch memory in this example, it behaves as expected, memory spikes and then falls at each iteration.  Now in my actual code (which is far more complicated)... we see the memory increase, but then upon return it does not decrease.

So what, conceptually, would be causing that.  Non-deleted references to the dict or to the underlying dataframes, right?  I've looked at the output of objgraph and there are no back references which should not be deleted upon function return.  (But I guess there must be).

One other thought: the only back reference to the dataframes in objgraph is a tuple.  Now this has happened because in my actual loop, the dataframe is created and ends up as of multiple return values passed as a tuple, so for example inner_sub_func() returns (float, float, int, DataFrame).  I guess this actual tuple is still floating around at the end of my main function.  But, as soon as the main function exits and we return to **main** so to speak, shouldn't that tuple get wiped?

```
def func():
    DICT_OF_DF = {}
    for i in range (0, 1000):
        DICT_OF_DF[i] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random([1000, 1000]))
    DICT_OF_DF.clear()
    del DICT_OF_DF
    gc.collect()
    return 42

for j in range(0, 100000):
    print('Running func #{}'.format(j))
    func()
    debug = True
```

Comment: _I know I've only provided general information, but my specific code is very complex and long, so I'm really looking for any general advice_ Would it be possible to make a [mcve], though? This sounds strange, I would like to be able to run it myself.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot isolate the specific part to produce a small sample like that.  Here's one additional thing I found.  Upon watching the memory allocation during execution, it clearly increases when new dataframes are made.   So it must be related to that.  I used objgraph to look at the references and back references on these dataframes right at the end of the function - prior to return - and there is nothing that shouldn't go out of scope upon return.  But they seemingly stay in memory, or perhaps Python kills them but doesn't release the memory back to OS.

Comment: let me try to make a smaller example